# Port Forwarding for 2nd ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, port-forwarding

I have an ESXi running on my local network, with port forwarding to 443(TCP) and 902(TCP and UDP) for outside access (I also have firewall rules for access from only certain networks).  I can connect to it in browser using 'https://x.x.x.x'.

I just setup a 2nd ESXi on my local network, and am not sure on how to port forward to it on my router, nor how I would connect to it outside my network.  Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: The obvious solution is IPv6, which you should already have deployed in your network.

Comment: IPv6 may be an alternative in parts of the world where it’s generally deployed. Here in my not-quite-urban part of Sweden I can only get it on higher-end business Internet connections. Telia, the biggest ISP and phone operator here, provides IPv4 only in both LTE networks and in regular home connections, and anyone using their infrastructure is stuck with what they support.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it would be more secure not to present the hypervisor management interfaces directly to the Internet.

That said, presenting multiple services via a single IP-address/port combination can be done with a reverse proxy; for example HAProxy.